# How can I create new ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> from an old one without changing the old one?

Tags: java, list, reference

I have an `ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> res` whic contains some subsets of integers. Part of these subsets I keep in `ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> prev`. For example `res = [[1], [1, 2], [2]]` and `prev = [[1, 2], [2]]`. Then I want to create new `ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> tmp` which is a copy of `prev`, to add new element in each subset of `tmp` **without** changing `prev` and then to add `tmp` to the result. The code that I use is the following:

```
ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> res = new ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>>();
  ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> prev = new ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>>();
  for (int i = 0; i < S.length; i++) {
    ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> tmp = new ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>>();
    if(something){
      tmp = new ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>>(prev);
      for(ArrayList<Integer> a: tmp){
        a.add(S[i]);
      }
      res.addAll(tmp);
      prev = new ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>>(tmp);
}
```

So if `res = [[1], [1, 2], [2]]` and `prev = [[1, 2], [2]]` `S[i] = 2` I want tmp to become `[[1, 2, 2], [2, 2]]` and then to add `tmp` to `res`. The problem is that when I add element to `tmp`, I change also `prev` and I change also `res`, which I don't want. So after the above iteration my `res` contains `[[1], [1, 2, 2], [2, 2], [1, 2, 2], [2, 2]]` instead of `[[1], [1, 2], [2], [1, 2, 2], [2, 2]]`. I tried changing this line  `tmp = new ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>>(prev);` with `tmp.addAll(prev);` but it didnt work again. Where is my mistake?

**EDIT:**

I think I solved the problem - I changed the line `tmp = new ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>>(prev);` to

```
for(ArrayList<Integer> a: prev){
    tmp.add(new ArrayList<Integer>(a));
}
```

However, I still need an explenation why this works, and why the previous doesnt work?

Comment: What is the variable S on the code? Could you please show me the other part of the code?

Comment: @BrunoFranco the variable S[i] is integer. I think I fixed the problem - changed ` tmp = new ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>>(prev);` to `for(ArrayList<Integer> a: prev){
 tmp.add(new ArrayList<Integer>(a));
}`

Comment: Rather than editing your question to include the solution (which I think is correct), you should post the solution separately as an answer. Answering your own question is fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
tmp = new ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>>(prev)
```

This creates a *shallow* copy, which is a new top-level `ArrayList` that contains the same references as the original. The members of `tmp` are references to the exact same objects that are still in `prev`.

You need to make a *deep* copy of the entire structure, which is what you accomplished with your edit.

Note that the `Integer` objects are immutable. Thus it's OK to refer to them from multiple places, so *they* don't need to be duplicated.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that you are changing the original list values (passing them by reference)
I think that you have to use `clone()` to avoid side-effects.

The code should be like:

```
  ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> prev = new ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>>();
      for (int i = 0; i < SCloned.length; i++) {
    ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> SCloned = (ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>>)S.clone();
        ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> tmp = new ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>>();
```

Then do `a.add(SCloned[i]);` (**UNTESTED**)